# Restricting portrait orientation to collectionview in iOS doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have multiple viewControllers in my app and I would like to restrict certain views only to portrait orientation. I have achieved this by overriding shouldAutoRotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations like below

```
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {

        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue)
    }
```

I have followed the same for a UICollectionView but it doesn't seem to work. I would like to know if this is the right way to achieve it. Help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` are `UIViewController` methods. They're not supported on `UIView`s, such as `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @akashivskyy please can you tell how do I achieve the same in Collectionview?

Comment: It's impossible. View cannot declare orientation settings, only view **controllers** can. It can't be done unless you meant `UICollectionViewController`.

Comment: Yes! I did mean it as UICollectionViewController.

Comment: @akashivskyy little help on this would be great…

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 or later, if you want to control the allowed orientations per view controller:

1. Make sure the "Supported interface orientations" in the `Info.plist` allows all orientations you want the app to be able to use. (Or just check the correct "Device Orientations" in the Xcode UI interface to the `Info.plist`file)
2. Per view controller, implement (example restricting to portrait):

   ```
   override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
   }
   ```

A problem you can run in to is if your view controller is embedded in another view controller (like an UINavigationController or a UITabBarController, or both).

I suspect this is the situation you are describing.

If so, all view controllers involved need to implement the `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` method. AFAIK, if you for example have a UINavigationController above your view controller, you need to sub class and create your own navigation controller with the method implemented.